# Ruby- creating an hash from an array of hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I have an array of hashes:

```
@operating_systems = [
  {"title"=>"iPhone", "value_percent"=>"42.6"},
  {"title"=>"Windows 7", "value_percent"=>"21.3"},
  {"title"=>"Android", "value_percent"=>"12.8"},
  {"title"=>"Mac OS X", "value_percent"=>"8.5"},
  {"title"=>"Windows 8.1", "value_percent"=>"6.4"},
  {"title"=>"Windows XP", "value_percent"=>"4.3"},
  {"title"=>"Linux", "value_percent"=>"2.1"},
  {"title"=>"Windows Vista", "value_percent"=>"2.1"}
]
```

and want to create the following hash:

```
 {"iphone" => "42.6", "windows 7" => "21.3", ... "windows vista" => "2.1"}
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Write the logic behind the conversion. Don't let the reader guess. As of now, none of the given answers got your intention correctly, and that is because you have not made it clear.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your comment.  All three answers correctly solve my question, so it would appear that they indeed understand the intention, no?

Comment: @dmt2989 I don't understand your mind. All the three answers given at the time of my comment above give different result from what you wanted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[
  {"title"=>"iPhone", "value_percent"=>"42.6"},
  {"title"=>"Windows 7", "value_percent"=>"21.3"},
  {"title"=>"Android", "value_percent"=>"12.8"},
  {"title"=>"Mac OS X", "value_percent"=>"8.5"},
  {"title"=>"Windows 8.1", "value_percent"=>"6.4"},
  {"title"=>"Windows XP", "value_percent"=>"4.3"},
  {"title"=>"Linux", "value_percent"=>"2.1"},
  {"title"=>"Windows Vista", "value_percent"=>"2.1"}
]
.map{|h| h.values.map(&:downcase)}.to_h
# =>
# {
#   "iphone"=>"42.6",
#   "windows 7"=>"21.3",
#   "android"=>"12.8",
#   "mac os x"=>"8.5",
#   "windows 8.1"=>"6.4",
#   "windows xp"=>"4.3",
#   "linux"=>"2.1",
#   "windows vista"=>"2.1"
# }
```

Comment: I don't see how to improve on this. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way

```
 op_sys =  [{"title"=>"iPhone", "value_percent"=>"42.6"}, {"title"=>"Windows 7", "value_percent"=>"21.3"}, {"title"=>"Android", "value_percent"=>"12.8"}, {"title"=>"Mac OS X", "value_percent"=>"8.5"}, {"title"=>"Windows 8.1", "value_percent"=>"6.4"}, {"title"=>"Windows XP", "value_percent"=>"4.3"}, {"title"=>"Linux", "value_percent"=>"2.1"}, {"title"=>"Windows Vista", "value_percent"=>"2.1"}] 

    new_hash = op_sys.inject({}) {|r,e| r[e['title']] = e['value_percent']; r}

    p new_hash
```

EDIT

You may have wanted the new hash keys to be in downcase... so an alternative:

```
new_hash = op_sys.inject({}) {|r,e| r[e['title'].downcase] = e['value_percent']; r}
```

Comment: (shrug) the Ruby style guide disagrees... "Rely on the fact that as of Ruby 1.9 hashes are ordered."  However I take your point that explicitly examining for "title" and "value_percent" keys are more robust. I'll rework the answer.

Comment: I've been bit by relying on the insertion order before (when dealing with outside data like JSON), it hurt :|

Comment: @user2864740 Are you sure this is correct? It doesn't look so to me.

Comment: @sawa It is semantically correct (http://ideone.com/8xukR8), although the variable names are a bit confusing as `r` is the accumulator hash and `e` is each item (hash) in the original array ..

Comment: hi, yes, sorry, `r` was my mental place-holder for "result" and `e` was my mental place-holder for "element in array". `r` is the accumulated result (an assembled hash) that will be returned to `new_hash` and `e` represents each element in the original array.

Comment: That is not the problem. The output is different from the expected output.

Comment: @sawa It matches the expected output. Be interested in hearing your thoughts as to why not.  Ah, wait, you mean the case!?!

Comment: @SteveTurczyn If you insist that it matches, then I cannot say anything more. It looks like we are in different worlds.

Comment: LOL!  Gee, just say "he wants downcase keys", no need to be cryptic, @sawa :)

Comment: To be blamed is not you, but the OP's sloppiness.

Comment: `each_with_object` might be a little nicer than `inject` in this case, that would let you get rid of the  `;r` at the end of your block.

Answer (score 1):

@Sawa came the closest to what I'd do:

```
operating_systems = [
  {"title"=>"iPhone", "value_percent"=>"42.6"},
  {"title"=>"Windows 7", "value_percent"=>"21.3"},
  {"title"=>"Android", "value_percent"=>"12.8"},
  {"title"=>"Mac OS X", "value_percent"=>"8.5"},
  {"title"=>"Windows 8.1", "value_percent"=>"6.4"},
  {"title"=>"Windows XP", "value_percent"=>"4.3"},
  {"title"=>"Linux", "value_percent"=>"2.1"},
  {"title"=>"Windows Vista", "value_percent"=>"2.1"}
] 
operating_systems.map(&:values).to_h 
# => {"iPhone"=>"42.6",
#     "Windows 7"=>"21.3",
#     "Android"=>"12.8",
#     "Mac OS X"=>"8.5",
#     "Windows 8.1"=>"6.4",
#     "Windows XP"=>"4.3",
#     "Linux"=>"2.1",
#     "Windows Vista"=>"2.1"}
```

Which works on Ruby 2.1+.

Or, on older versions of Ruby:

```
Hash[operating_systems.map(&:values)] 
# => {"iPhone"=>"42.6",
#     "Windows 7"=>"21.3",
#     "Android"=>"12.8",
#     "Mac OS X"=>"8.5",
#     "Windows 8.1"=>"6.4",
#     "Windows XP"=>"4.3",
#     "Linux"=>"2.1",
#     "Windows Vista"=>"2.1"}
```

If folding the keys to lowercase is needed use these to replace the above commands:

```
operating_systems.map{ |h| k, v = h.values; [k.downcase, v] }.to_h
# => {"iphone"=>"42.6",
#     "windows 7"=>"21.3",
#     "android"=>"12.8",
#     "mac os x"=>"8.5",
#     "windows 8.1"=>"6.4",
#     "windows xp"=>"4.3",
#     "linux"=>"2.1",
#     "windows vista"=>"2.1"}

Hash[operating_systems.map{ |h| k, v = h.values; [k.downcase, v] }]
# => {"iphone"=>"42.6",
#     "windows 7"=>"21.3",
#     "android"=>"12.8",
#     "mac os x"=>"8.5",
#     "windows 8.1"=>"6.4",
#     "windows xp"=>"4.3",
#     "linux"=>"2.1",
#     "windows vista"=>"2.1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

While there are a number of more clever approaches, a simple loop over the source array with modification of the output hash will suffice; consider

```
arr = [{"title"=>"iPhone", "value_percent"=>"42.6"}, ..]

hash = {}
arr.each do |item|
   key = item["title"]
   value = item["value_percent"]
   hash[key] = value
end
```

and see the [ideone demo](http://ideone.com/UdUGHe). This is a very easy task, and I hope that how it was "solved" is made readily apparent above - there is no "best" until there is "working".

---

Once the basic approach is understood, the same process that was done (a transformation and then building a map from pairs) can be done as so

```
hash = Hash[arr.map do |v| [v["title"], v["value_percent"]] end]
```

Is this "better"? *shrug*, I guess it's "shorter" and still clear.. (and any additional transformation can be trivially added)

Comment: @dmt2989 Then the `arr` variable (or whatever is substituting it in your code) evaluates to `nil` and it ends up as `nil.each do ..` which results in the descriptive exception.

Comment: yea, that is odd, because I can display @arr in my view, and it's [{"title"=>"iPhone", "value_percent"=>"42.6"}, ..]

Comment: @dmt2989 The error message is telling the truth. Either `@arr` hasn't been set to a non-nil value yet (or has been reset?) or that code is running in a different scope.

Comment: My mistake- this also worked, but a different error was confounding the problem.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: @dmt2989 Glad the problem is solved! Make sure to write/use code that you (and others) can understand later.

Comment: Stylistically, don't use `do`/`end` on single-line blocks.

Comment: @theTinMan Mere preference. I find it more clear than another set of `{}` in this case due to the outer `Hash[]` - although if it were formatted on multiple lines or replaced, so be it.

Answer (score 0):

Combine `Enumerable#reduce` with `Hash#merge`

```
op_sys.reduce({}) { |hsh, itx| hsh.merge({ itx["title"] => itx["value_percent"]}) }
 => {"iPhone"=>"42.6", "Windows 7"=>"21.3", "Android"=>"12.8", "Mac OS X"=>"8.5", "Windows 8.1"=>"6.4", "Windows XP"=>"4.3", "Linux"=>"2.1", "Windows Vista"=>"2.1"}
```